# Cannot upload spreadsheet into table on SupaBase

Tags: spreadsheet, supabase, supabase-database

I am very new to SupaBase and this is my first time using it. Please help if you can.
I am having trouble uploading my spread sheet into a table on SupaBase. I get the error
“Failed to import data: Failed to run sql query: null value in column ‘Business NAME’ of relation ‘Test 3’ violates not-null constraint”

I tried to change the default value from NULL to empty sting but that didn’t work either.
As for what I am expecting, I was expecting to be able to upload my data spread sheet into the table but I don’t fully know how to do it properly.

Comment: You can make your `Business NAME` column nullable.